# .NETTY: Second batch of data sent includes the first?

Tags: c#, .net, azure, netty

I've noticed that when I run the decoder for dotnetty it includes the previous data. I'm not sure why, but the first packet (data) goes through fine, the second bit of data the client sends for some reason includes both parts of data, the previous processed data.

I've checked the client and the client doesn't send them both, the server just receives them both, I feel like this is something that DotNetty is doing?

```
internal class JsonToPacketDecoder : ByteToMessageDecoder
{
    protected override void Decode(IChannelHandlerContext context, IByteBuffer input, List<object> output)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Decoding: " + input.ToString(Encoding.UTF8) + " \n");
        output.Add(new IncomingPacket(JObject.Parse(input.ToString(Encoding.UTF8)).ToFlatDictionary()));
    }
}
```

It seems `input.ToString(Encoding.UTF8)` includes both?

Answer (score 0):

This problem is happening because `ToString(Encoding)`, while showing the contents, doesn't consume any input bytes.

Why is this? This because the usual use case of the "to string" function isn't in spaces where actual read bytes matter, because it basically reads all bytes every time, even when 2 "packets" have received.

The actual use case of a toString would be inside a handler where the framing of the packets into proper chunks has already been done.

What you probably want is a [`DelimiterBasedFrameDecoder`](https://github.com/Azure/DotNetty/blob/dev/src/DotNetty.Codecs/DelimiterBasedFrameDecoder.cs) that splits up your incoming stream into packets seperated by newlines or null bytes, then using a [ChannelHandlerAdapter](https://github.com/Azure/DotNetty/blob/dev/src/DotNetty.Transport/Channels/ChannelHandlerAdapter.cs), where you decode the packets to JSON.